# NSPredicate filter the data via relationship rather than a property

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate, relationship

Here is my question. I have this model one [Event] has multiple [Day] and there is a relationship called days in [Event] and there is a reverse relationship event in [Day].

Now I want pass the Event object and get all days using NSFetchedResultsController and feed all days in the table. Here is my code:

```
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Day" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

//set predicate  ->  ??
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"event = %@", self.currentEvent];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

//set entity
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                       cacheName:nil];
```

Somehow, the NSFetchedResultsController instance will always return the same thing for different event.
How should I fix the NSPredicate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", self.currentEvent.days];
```